# calculate definite integrals in terms of area

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

(a) Graph the function
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
2 - \sqrt{4 - x^2}, & -2 \leq x \leq 2 \\
|x - 5| - 1, & x > 2 
\end{cases}
$$
on the interval  [-2, 6]  and use it to calculate the definite integral
$$
\int_{-2}^{6} f(x) \, dx
$$
in terms of area.

I graphed the functions, and it is a semi-circle that lies on the x-axis plus two lines Then I calculated it by area and it is half square minus half semi-circle which is 8-2pi and the other two triangles are 1 and 2 so the total area is 11-2pi, but if I calculate the definite integrals in the interval [-2,6] the answer is 9-2pi. I feel confused that Should I count the area below the x-axis as negative in this question?

Comment: Definite integral = *signed* area, not area

Comment: Please use MathJax. https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Answer (score 4):

So, a visual of that function is below: positive area in blue, negative in red:

[image]

> Should I count the area below the x-axis as negative in this question?

Yes. The integral gives the *signed* area. You are being told to calculate the integral, using the area as the motivation (but that doesn't mean the area ***is*** the answer). So the bit on $[4,6]$ needs to be subtracted, not added; correcting for this fixes your answer.

Conversely, if told to find the (total, unsigned) area, it would not be enough necessarily to calculate the integral.

Comment: Thank You ! This well solved my confusion!

Answer (score -1):

Here are the Matlab code and the plot of function:

[image]

And for integrating the function in terms of the area, you can split the area into two parts: one is a rectangle minus semicircle, and another is the sum of two triangles.